# Sharing variables & structures at header files all over the program

Tags: c, variables, global-variables, header-files, structure

I am having a huge problem sharing global variables and 3 structures in the whole c files of my program.I am aware that the use of global variables may not be the best approach,but that seems to suit me for now.

The 2 usual errors that appear are:

Undefined reference for variable_name

error expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘%3b’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before variable_name

What i am trying to do is:

Define my global variables at variables.h and variables.c

Define the functions are file1.h, file2.h etc.

like :

file1.h :

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

void function_file1(void);

#endif
```

file1.c :

```
#include "file1.h"

void function_file1(void) {
//do sth
}
```

I define the global variables and structs as extern in variables.h and then again without the extern keyword at variables.c

However after doing that over and over again i keep on getting the 2 above errors.Is there something i am missing?

Here is more information about what i have done:

variables.h:

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H


extern int x;
extern int y;
extern int foo = 3; // i have set value to 3 variables with extern like the foo one


    /*Tooltips  */
struct test_struct {
/* variables 
*/

} test;

extern struct test_struct test;

#endif
```

functions.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include "variables.h"

void do_sth(void) { 
//do sth
}

#endif
```

main.c

```
/* including libraries before including variables.h and functions.h */
#include "variables.h"
#include "functions.h"

........
```

This is the basic structure of the program.There is a single variables.h file which  contains the global variables.There are around 7 functions.h like files containing a couple of functions for the program.With this structure the compiler does not show any errors.

The question is:How can i make a .c file for every .h file that i have in the program?
Like variables.h and variables.c and functions.h and functions.c ?

Comment: You clearly haven't posted the code with the error in it. And I bet that the error message has a file name and a line number.

Comment: the reason i have not posted is because it is huge...what an irony huh? :( i would still highly appreciate how i would be able to define my functions at header and c files and share global variables and structures at them.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you posted, though you could try tossing 'extern' on the front of the header declaration. Again, look for a specific file name and line number in the error.

Comment: You only shall use `extern` for variables not for `struct`s. Also for `struct`s defined in a `*.h` file there is no need to redefine them in a `*.c` files.

Comment: @alk yes.i am aware of it! :) i tried something like that which i guess its correct extern struct my_new_struct my_new;

Comment: @bmargulies i will update my post in a while with most info and examples so that its easier to help

Comment: After trying to compile one source file i get this error from variables.h  error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘var_name ’ which repeats for every following line which contains a variable

Answer (score 0):

First of all re-think whether it really make sense to separate variables and functions per se.

Generally there are relations between some variabels and some functions. Follwoing such relations a grouping might make more sense.

Group variables and the functions working on them together.

Anyway to come back to your question, a possible way to define and declare your variables could be the following:

variables.h:

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H

extern int x;
extern int y;
extern int foo;

struct test_struct {
/* variables 
*/

};

extern struct test_struct test;

#endif
```

variables.c:

```
#include "variables.h"    

int x;
int y;
int foo = 3; // i have set value to 3 variables with extern like the foo one


struct test_struct test;

...
```

Include `variables.h` into any module making use of the externals and later let the linker add `variables.o` compiled out of `variables.c`.

Comment: i have already accepted another answer which was posted yesterday but its gone....thanks though